# Iframe switching is not working in firefox but working in chrome in Karate UI framework

Tags: iframe, karate

Tried switchFrame which works flawlessly in Chrome, but same does not work in Firfox, is there any alternate JS code or any method to overcome this issue ?

Comment: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1715 - this may be fixed in 1.2.0.RC4 so try that - else please contribute code, time or anything else to the project ! - but it is likely this is a fault in `geckodriver` so the best bet is for you to stick to chrome or **contribute code** to make Karate better !!

Comment: is there a way i can access native methods of webdriver instantiated using karate ?

Comment: yes, try this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test#webdriver-tips