# Facing this issue "Missing property in path $['frameTree']['childFrames']" while switching to an iframe which is a tokenex iframe

Tags: karate

```
Given driver redirectUrl
    And waitForText('body', 'Información de la tarjeta de crédito')
    And driver.maximize()
    And driver.screenshotFull()
    And waitFor("//*[@id='mat-input-0']")
    And input("//*[@id='mat-input-0']", '12/22')
    And waitForText('body', 'Número de Tarjeta de Crédito')
   
   
    And waitFor("//*[@name='tx_iframe_card-number']")
    And switchFrame("//iframe[@id='tx_iframe_card-number']")
    And waitFor("//*[@name='tx_iframe_card-number']")
    And input("input[name='tx_iframe_card-number']", '4622943127013705')
    And switchFrame(null)
```

Not able to switch to the iframe with id tx_iframe_card-number

Comment: iframes are hard. please be prepared to do some investigation or contribute code. your best starting point is here, I have no further suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70894996/143475